# Can I use nested DNS wildcard records

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to have multiple dns entries with wildcards such that one entry is nested as subdomain of another

```
CNAME *.example.com -> webserver.example.com
CNAME *.api.example.com -> apiserver.example.com
```

The intention being that I can use `customer.example.com` to access the webserver and `customer.api.example.com` to access the api server.

Since `customer.api.example.com` is a valid match for both of the wildcard entries i'm not sure how this will get resolved.

I have tested this on AWS route53 as the DNS provider and it seems to work as expected.`customer.api.example.com` resolved to the api server. But i'm not sure if this is guaranteed by the DNS spec or was just chance it picked the correct server.

Is this behaviour something I can rely on to be consistent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This approach is ok, DNS server use the most specific match which is `*.api.example.com` for `customer.api.example.com` The behavior should be consistent because is defined in [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.3)